# Java:Replace specific word with other content unchanged

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am new here and would you like to help me?

There may be lines like

> 389   392   "magnifyingglas"   1   0   4   392   6616   0    8529270
>   0   |
>
> 390   391   "armourstand"   1   0   6   391   6630   0   6800   0   |
>
> 391   391   "weaponrack"   1   0   6   390   6631   0   6800   0   |

I want to subtract 20 from  the second number.

Like

> 390   391   "armourstand"   1   0   6   391   6630   0   6800   0   |

To

> 390   371   "armourstand"   1   0   6   391   6630   0   6800   0   |

But I don't know how to do it.

I may get the second number,then I don't know how to do with it.
There may be same numbers in this line,but I just want to replace the second number.

Thanks a lot.

============================================================================
update

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\s+3(9)[0-2]\\s\S+\\s+(1)\\s+\\d\\s+6") ;
            Matcher m = p.matcher("6621   391   \"weaponrack\"   1   0   6   371   6631   0   6800   0   |") ;
```

I want something like this

```
m.group(2).replace(7);
```

But I could find the similar method.

I see some documents say that we can use "$" to get the group reference, and it doesn't explain more.

Well, I read lines from text,  and use "^(\d+)\s+3(7)0-21(\s+\d\s+)6"
to find the matched line.
And then I need to replace the 39[0-2] to be 37[0-2].
It can be done by minus 20 or other ways which I don't care.

Comment: You can add some code and contextualize your doubt for a better understanding from the community

Comment: You just provide a better context of you are trying to do. I don't know what you are talking about. Do you always have 6 digits in your first number?

Answer (score 0):

Well,@Ctorres gives me an idea now.

When I get the matched line,put it in a char array.

First we skip the array first number,and blank spaces.

Then change the char'9' to be '7'.

But I think it's really complex.